# In Eclipse, how do I see the input to Assert.assertEquals when it fails?

Tags: eclipse, assert, junit4

I'm not much of an Eclipse guru, so please forgive my clumsiness.

In Eclipse, when I call Assert.assertEquals(obj1,obj2) and that fails, how do I get the IDE to show me obj1 and obj2?

I'm using [JExample](http://scg.unibe.ch/seaside/pier/research/jexample), but I guess that shouldn't make a difference.

---

**Edit**: Here's what I see:
 [image]
<sub>(source: [yfrog.com](http://img86.yfrog.com/img86/3002/jexample.png))</sub>
.

Comment: Given your error message, I presume that you used `assertSame` and not `assertEquals`. As mentioned in the other responses, `assertEquals` should print both values in the error message (given that `toString()` ain't broken as well).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the information in the JUnit view is not enough for you, you can always set a exception breakpoint on, for example, java.lang.AssertionError. When running the test, the debugger will stop immediately before the exception is actually being thrown.

Comment: Yup, I guess that'll do it. Although back when I used TestNG, I kind of enjoyed the column-view: expected left, actual on the right.

Answer (score 6):

1. Comparison with failure trace is not a easy task when your object is a little bit complex.
2. Comparison with debugger is useful if you have not redefined toString(). It remains still very tedious as solution because you should inspect with your eyes each objects from both sides.

Junit Eclipse plugin offers a option when there is a failure : "Compare actual With Expected TestResult". The view is close enough to classic content comparison tools :
[image: Comparison with String objects]

Problem is that it is avaiable only when you write`assertEquals()` with `String` objects (in the screenshot, we can see that the option in the corner is not proposed with no `String` class) :
[image: Comparison with no String objects]

You may use `toString()` on your object in assertion but it's not a good solution :

- firstly, you correlate `toString()` with `equals(Object)`... modification of one must entail modification of the other.
- secondly, the semantic is not any longer respected. `toString()` should return a useful method to debug the state of one object, not to identify an object in the Java semantic (`equals(Object)`).

According to me, I think that the JUnit Eclipse plugin misses a feature.
When comparison fails, even when we compare not `String` objects, it should offer a comparison of the two objects which rely on their `toString()` method. 
It could offer a minimal visual way of comparing two unequals objects. 
Of course, as `equals(Object)` is not necessarily correlated to `toString()`,  highlighted differences should be studied with our eyes but it would be already a very good basis and anyway, it is much better than no comparison tool.

Answer (score 2):

`Assert.assertEquals()` will put the `toString()` representation of the expected and actual object in the message of the `AssertionFailedError` it throws, and eclipse will display that in the "failure trace" part of the JUnit view:

[image]
<sub>(source: [ibm.com](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-xp042203/junitAssertionFailure.gif))</sub>

If you have complex objects you want to inspect, you'll have to use the debugger and put a breakpoint inside `Assert.assertEquals()`

Answer (score 1):

What are you seeing?

When you do assertTrue() and it fails, you see a null.

But when you do assertEquals, it is supposed to show you what it expected and what it actually got.

If you are using JUnit, mke sure you are looking at the JUnit view and moving the mouse to the failed test.

Answer (score 1):

[FEST Assert](http://code.google.com/p/fest/) will display comparison dialog in case of assertion failure even when objects you compare are not strings. I explained it in more detail [on my blog](http://piotrjagielski.com/blog/a-cool-technique-for-object-comparison-in-junit/).

Answer (score 0):

If what you are comparing is a String then you can double click stack element and it will popup a dialog showing the diff in eclipse.

This only works with Strings though. For the general case the only way to see the real reason is to install a breakpoint and step into it.