# eclipse junit differencies' window

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

Before , when I was working with JUnit under eclipse I used to double click on somewhere in JUnit view and then a comparison window popped up. Which showed exact differences(like version controle systems do, e.g git diff tools) between actual and expected.

And now I am not able find it again. Where is it? Or  Is it removed from new versions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You double-click on the failure in the JUnit view. Note that the diff is only available if the test fails with a `ComparisonFailure`

Comment: Which is assertEquals .  It makes sense now that it must a comparison.(assertThat is not/may not be). thanks

Comment: @user3354638 specifically, `assertEquals(String, String)` will throw `ComparisionFailureError` on failure

Comment: @NamshubWriter thank you for pointing to ComparisonFailureError - it's allowed me understand why assertEquals(CharSequence, CharSequence) did not work - and propose https://github.com/junit-team/junit/pull/949/ .. ;-)

Comment: @vorburger you're welcome. We would love to accept that pull request, but there are a few questions on the thread.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why this is only for String comparisons? I think it can be useful for the generic object comparison as well. *Typically* we write a good toString for the method that captures the essential elements in the object that are included in equals and hence the toString output *might* be a good proxy for a quick clickable diff that outlines the differences?

Comment: @Kilokahn's suggestion is also made in [this related post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5405791/3780389).  The post also considers using `assertEquals(obj1.toString(), obj2.toString())` as a work-around which I have found useful when debugging a failing assertion: to get the diff view, temporarily add the `toString()` version before the failing assertion. It would be nicer if eclipse just made the `toString()` diff view available for arbitrary `assertEquals`.

Comment: btw, isn't it `ComparisionFailure` rather than `ComparisionFailureError`?